# Upgrade to Angular 10 throws errors related to @ng-select/ng-select (Incompatible peer dependencies)

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I have problems when updating Angular app from version 9 to version 10.

[image]

You can see in the picture that there is an incompatible dependency. I know there are many questions asked around this but I was unable to solve the problem.

[image]

Also there is my package.json. I really appreciate your answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using --force?

Comment: nop, i was looking for another way before using --force

Comment: or maybe i force the update and then install ng-select, what do you say?

Comment: `--force` flag is not a solution. You need to upgrade ng-select library to the correct version (v5 for angular 10).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update your `ng-selct` version also. The version you are currently using is not compatible with `Angular 10`. Check their github readme below

https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select

You need to upgrade your `ng-select` version to 5

[image]

Comment: when i run npm install @ng-select/ng-select i get this error:
Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@">=8.0.0 <9.0.0" from @ng-select/ng-select@3.7.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select
npm ERR!   @ng-select/ng-select@"^3.6.1" from the root project

Comment: change version in package.json, then remove package-lock.json and run `npm i`

Comment: that worked for me, thanks

Comment: @Guido great. Please mark this accepted if everything working fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade the `@ng-select/ng-select` package version to v5(exactly 5.1.0 - last compatible):

https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/v5.1.0/package.json

This is the correct version for Angular 10.

Change version number in the `package.json` file and run `npm update` to fix this problem.